# Nexus Mod Manager won't recognize Fallout New Vegas

Tags: fallout-new-vegas, nexus-mod-manager

I have trouble opening NMM for my New vegas game saying that it does not have the permission to write the game and I've been told that I should run as admin to open it, but :

1. Can someone please explain it to me how to do it ?
2. Also will this affect my Skyrim game as I've also have the game modded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you have New Vegas installed to a restricted location. (`Program Files`, maybe?)

To fix this, you'll just need to do exactly what it asked you to. Right-click your NMM shortcut on your desktop and select *Run as administrator*. To save yourself from having to do this all the time, right-click the shortcut, select *Properties*, go to the *Compatibility* tab, tick *Run this program as an administrator*, and then click *OK*.

Answer (score 0):

If you torrented the game, that would be the obvious issue.  If not, though, try reinstalling it to the directory NMM looks for.